# Ordenar un array sin usar .sort en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function, javascript-objeto

tengo un ejerciocio donde me pieden
Escribir una función en JavaScript que reciba como parámetro un array compuesto
por números enteros y retorne un nuevo array con las siguientes características:
El nuevo array debe estar compuesto por los elementos que ocupan las
posiciones pares en el array recibido, elevados al cuadrado.
Y También deben estar ordenados de menor a mayos sin usar .sort

```js
var arrayNumbers = [4, 30, 7, 5, 9, 7, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2];

function numberPar (arrayNumbers){
    let newArray = [];
    let max = arrayNumbers[0];

    for(let i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i+= 2){
        newArray.push(arrayNumbers[i]* arrayNumbers[i])
        
    }

    return newArray;

}

numberPar (arrayNumbers)
```

esa es la función que genere pero no puedo lograr que quede ordenado el array sin usar .sort

Comment: Esto es buscar algoritmos de ordenamiento, hay varios, bubble, quicksort se me vienen a la mente, cada uno con sus pro y contras.. te dejo un enlace donde hablan de los mismos https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-guide-to-sorting-algorithms-in-javascript-5b32da4eae1e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente algorítmo tiene [Quadratic Time Complexity O(n^2)](https://jarednielsen.com/big-o-quadratic-time-complexity/) y va intercambiando los elementos del `array`:

```js
var arrayNumbers = [4, 30, 7, 5, 9, 7, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2];

function numberPar (arrayNumbers){
    let newArray = [];
    let max = arrayNumbers[0];

    for(let i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i+= 2){
        newArray.push(arrayNumbers[i]* arrayNumbers[i])
        
    }
    
    let dataLen = newArray.length;
    //console.log("dataLen",dataLen);
    for(let i=0; i < dataLen; i++){
      for(let j=0; j < dataLen; j++){
        if(j+1 !== dataLen){
          if(newArray[j] > newArray[j+1]){
            let swapElement = newArray[j+1];
            newArray[j+1] = newArray[j];
            newArray[j] = swapElement;
          }
        }  
      }
    }
    //console.log(newArray)
    return newArray;
}

console.log("Sort menor a mayor:",numberPar (arrayNumbers));
```

Lo que sugiero, es que vayas depurando este ejemplo con un `diagrama de flujo` para que tenga más sentido.

---

#### Notas de campo

Los siguientes algoritmos de sorting son O(n^2):

- Selection sort
- Insertion sort
- Bubble sort

Comment: Esto es de gran ayuda, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hice esta solucion sencilla en js.

```javascript
function sort(n, array) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    var anterior = array[index - 1];
    var indexAnterior = index - 1;
    if (anterior == undefined) {
      array[index] = array[index];
    }

    if (array[index] >= anterior) {
      array[indexAnterior + 1] = array[index];
    }

    if (array[index] <= anterior) {
      console.log(anterior);
      array[indexAnterior] = array[index];
      array[index] = anterior;
    }
  }
  console.log(array);
}

sort(5, [2, 0, 1, 0, 2]);
```

Comment: ¿Qué es el parámetro `n` de la función? No veo que se use dentro de la función.  Deberias explicar mínimamente lo que has hecho para que todos lo podamos entender, gracias. Léete [como escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).